# Remove escape from serialized NSSdictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, serialization, nsurlrequest

I am pretty new to serializing with json, and I am facing a weird issue.

I am trying to send an NSURLRequest with a josn. The json is first stored into an NSSMutableDictionary and eventually is serialized. The serialized json object I get is escaped, meaning it has "\" in it all over the place.

The json is getting sent a server, but is getting denied. According to the admin the json is getting denied because its escaped. How can I removed all the back slashes from the serialized json before sending it.

HELP. I tried creating an NSString then converting to NSData then serialized and failed. I tried NSArray and failed. At least I think I did those correctly.

Did I make a mistake somewhere? is there a better way to do this?

Thanks,
Sam.

Comment: Please show some code

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the same problem try AFNetworking
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

[manager GET:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:nil   success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);


    NSlog(@"value->%@", [responseObject objectForKey@"json_key"]);


} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

}];
```

Comment: So this sample code is sending an HTTP post request?

Comment: Yes it does and if you go to the github you will find how to pass parameter values I case you need them